# Probability involing percentages (Bernoulli?)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, bernoulli-numbers

Assume that about 56% of population belong to group type of O. 
A) What is the probability that it will need to take a blood test from exactly three individuals in order to find a person with O-type blood? 
B) What is the probability that it will need to take more than 4 blood tests? 
My attempt of A): 
n  = 3 
k = ? 
n-k = 3-? 
p = 56% = 14/25 
q = 1-p = 11/25 
C(n,k)p^k * q^(n-k)
I am not sure how to use given information to solve this problem. Can you give me any hint please?

Answer (score 1):

We want the probability that we try once, fail, try again, fail, try again, got it. So the probability is $(0.44)(0.44)(0.56)$.  .

For B), we want the probability that we fail $4$ times in a row. For that's exactly the situation in which we need more than $4$ trials.

**Remark:** It is best to get a handle on the problem, then use (if necessary) the appropriate formula.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! You're awesome :). It is actually what I was thinking, but it is homework so I was expecting something a bit more complicated that's why I gave up on my first attempts and went straight forward to Bernoulli..